# javascript show hide div by id issue

Tags: javascript, html, hide

I have a list with divs that contain information for cities. 
    I have also a list of the cities so visitor can click on a city and than all other's cities divs must hide.
    If visitor clicks back on the city link the hidden divs must show again. 
    So far I have a working function but it only works fo London. If I click on Paris - no errors and no actions. 
    What causes this? Thanks

UPDATED

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">      
function showHideDiv(city_id) {    
var divstyle = new String();    
divstyle = document.getElementById(city_id).style.visibility;    
if (divstyle.toLowerCase() == "visible" || divstyle == "") {     
document.getElementById("city_id").style.visibility = "hidden";    
document.getElementById("city_id").style.position = "absolute";             
}else{     
document.getElementById("city_id").style.visibility = "visible";    
document.getElementById("city_id").style.position = "relative";    
}    
}    
$(document).ready(function() {    
$(".city").click(function() {    
$(this).toggle();    
});    
});    
</script>    
<a href="#" id="<?php echo $city;?>" onclick="showHideDiv()" style="text-decoration:underline;">London | Paris</a></div>    
<div id="London">List of providers in London here as content</div>    
<div id="Paris">List of providers in Paris here as content</div>
```

Comment: What did `console.log` tell you? And what's that output code? Did `showHideDiv` actually called?

Comment: 1) only "var divstyle;" 2) seems like style "display:block;" would do the same you try to accomplish setting both position and visibility 3) show us the actual code AFTER php has run, the one in the browser, since this is where you have the problem

Comment: yes showHideDiv is working, but only for the first city, no errors come from the console

Comment: if I alert the id of the element it alerts London, but for the rest cities alert is blank I don't know how to debug it for more information, php outputs a list with cities and I am using <div id="<?php echo $row['town'];?>" to generate each div ID's and it is OK

Answer (score 2):

I would imagine it has to do with the fact that your Javascript has the city hard coded in it. I presume (without seeing the PHP) that you are echoing "London" here:

```
<?php echo $city;?>
```

So anytime showHideDiv() is called, it only gets called on London, and not Paris. You probably need to pass in the id as a parameter into the function.

You may consider looking at jQuery. It would make this easy.

**EDIT**

Using your code, you'd pass in the parameter as follows:

```
function showHideDiv(city_id) {
    var divstyle = new String();
    divstyle = document.getElementById(city_id).style.visibility;
    // . . . Rest of your code. Replace all instances of <?php echo . . ?> with 
    // city_id.
}
```

Then you'd have to specify the city in your onclick for each city.

Using jQuery, you could do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".city").click(function() {
        $(this).toggle();
    });
});
```

And then your HTML would be:

```
<div id="london" class="city">List of providers in London</div>
<div id="paris" class="city">List of providers in Paris</div>
```

Comment: and how to do that please?
I check for jquery but didn't find working solution, as I am not scripter I am using nearly ready solutions, so if you have one in mind please post it, thanks

Comment: See my edit. I'd recommend learning Javascript, it would make this task much easier.

Comment: Louis, still doesn't work and no errors, I replace all suggested and still doesn't work..

Comment: I'm having a tough time divining your code. Could you post the updated version somewhere?

Comment: now I see this error document.getElementById(city_id) is null, Ok I will paste it again as edit, give me one minute please

Comment: . . . did you actually pass it anything? Again, it's hard for anyone to help without seeing what you updated.

Comment: city_id is not a string it's a parameter. Remove the quotes . . . Your're also not passing anything into showHideDiv(), it takes a parameter now. Take some time to learn javascript.

Comment: @Мариян Маринов: Consider creating a fiddle (jsfiddle.net) if you want THAT type of help.

Comment: still the same error document.getElementById(city_id) is null after I removed quotes..

Comment: Because you pass nothing into the function. As @Mörre stated, create a jsfiddle if you want more help. I'm tired of guessing.

Comment: Yes: Take some time to learn Javascript. I literally gave you the answer above.

Comment: Dear Lous, if I could manage with learning I would not waste your time ! Some things need explanations or examples to get the core of the things.. 
I changed the js script and now I implemented jquery here: http://jsfiddle.net/KcKgC/     
Please have a look at it - it works without any errors, but still shows and hides only the first element. I have hardcored the cities, so it is not php issue. In my tests php is well and even js alerts and counts correct the number of divs with same class. It is a js missunderstanding.. Please help with this , Thanks

Comment: In addition I can confirm that I made previous js script above to work, but since it catches the divs by id and there was several divs with same id id hide only the first London divs and first Paris div, so that's why I went to jquery by classes, not by id.. but still can't make it working..